# Is fast data access related to the availability (A) in CAP theorem?

Tags: bigdata, distributed-database, cap-theorem

I realize that it will be a basic concept, but it would be helpful if anyone could explain if fast data access related to the availability (A) in CAP theorem. Fast data access is an important feature expected of Big Data systems. And does the various K-Access and K-grouping method all a part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Availability in CAP theorem is about whether you can access your data even if there is failure in the hardware (e.g. network outage, node outage etc).

Fast access to large volume of data is important feature observed in most of the big data systems. But, it should not confused with availability as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Availability in CAP theorem means that all your requests will receive a response, but does not specify **when** or **how accurate**. Nor does it specify what *fast* could mean.

> Every request receives a (non-error) response – without guarantee that
>   it contains the most recent write

Keep in mind that this theorem enforces **strict guarantees**. For example, systems can guarantee C and A, and still be good at P most of the time.